# Running a ES6 application on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to deploy a simple NodeJs Express application to Heroku. It's in ES6. I've found a few articles but they were outdated claiming that I'd need babel added to my dependencies. Therefore, what mandatory dependencies do I have to have these days in order to run an minimal ES6 application on Heroku?

Comment: If you have a modern node running on the server, it will have ES6 features. AFAIK babel is just for making es6 browser code retrocompatible, and has nothing to do with the fact that heroku hosts your server.

Answer (score 2):

The [ES6 features](http://node.green/) for any version of Node.

The [default Node versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#supported-runtimes) used in Heroku.

[How to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) configure the Node version for your app on Heroku.

Comment: So no need for babel ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, the question here was about mandatory dependencies, but generally speaking for Node you won't need Babel. If you want to transpile some code you are sending to the browser, that is a different question.